# Generating more than one CSV File using DataTables Data on ASP.NET MVC using WebAPI and highlight Cell based on the condition

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc, angular, asp.net-web-api

I have ASP.NET MVC AngularJS/JQuery Application which makes WebAPI calls for returning the data back.

I have to read the data from the database table and generate two CSV files.

Here I drafted the code with sample DataTable data and here we have two different tables since their columns are different. I have to generate both the CSV Files on button Click itself.

```
public IHttpActionResult GenerateValidationCSVFiles(string submissionId)
    {
        try
        {
            //Based on the SubmissionID, we get data 
            //Account Table 
            DataTable tblAccount = new DataTable();

            tblAccount.Columns.Add("AccountID", typeof(int));
            tblAccount.Columns.Add("NAME", typeof(string));
            tblAccount.Columns.Add("Email", typeof(string));

            tblAccount.Rows.Add(111, "John", "John@abc.com");
            tblAccount.Rows.Add(222, "Mike", "Mike@xyz.com");
            tblAccount.Rows.Add(102, "Meghan", "Meghan@123.com");

            //Location Table
            DataTable tblLocation = new DataTable();

            tblLocation.Columns.Add("AccountID", typeof(int));
            tblLocation.Columns.Add("LocName", typeof(string));
            tblLocation.Columns.Add("Address", typeof(string));
            tblLocation.Columns.Add("CITY", typeof(string));
            tblLocation.Columns.Add("Zipcode", typeof(string));

            tblLocation.Rows.Add(111, "John", "123 Lake Dr", "Newyork", "12345");
            tblLocation.Rows.Add(222, "Mike", "456 test Dr", "Kansas", "");
            tblLocation.Rows.Add(102, "Meghan", "345 Texico Pl", "San Francisco", "");
            tblLocation.Rows.Add(212, "Steve", "8989 Williow Cir", "Chicago", "");

            //Write logic to render as CSV File data
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            ILog Log = LogManager.GetLogger(System.Reflection.MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().DeclaringType);
            Log.Error("ERROR : " + ex.ToString());
            return Ok(ex.ToString());
        }
    }
```

Here I have sample Validation Rule like in the Location file, if Zipcode is not Empty, highlight that cell in Yellow color.

What is the best way to generate CSV files using DataTable data and highlight the Cell? Whether to highlight on the Server side or CLient side and How?

Appreciate your responses.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I can provide some answers for the server-side portion of the issue given the context but not the client-side. You'll be looking to serialize the table data to CSV format:

```
//Convert table to CSV-formatted string

//Add header
StringBuilder accountSB = new StringBuilder();
for (int i = 0; i < tblAccount.Columns.Count; i++)
{
    string columnName = tblAccount.Columns[i].ColumnName);
    accountSB.Append("\"" + columnName + "\"");
    if (i < tblAccount.Columns.Count - 1)
        accountSB.Append(',');
}

accountSB.AppendLine();

//Add row data
foreach (DataRow dr in tblAccount.Rows)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < tblAccount.Columns.Count; i++)
    {
        accountSB.Append("\"" + dr[i].ToString() + "\"");

        if (i < tblAccount.Columns.Count - 1)
            accountSB.Append(',');
    }
    accountSB.AppendLine();
}

//Further processing...
```

As for returning the files, I think the only consistent way to return multiple files in a single HTTP response across an array of browsers would be to zip them in a single file. Alternatively you could return a single CSV file per response. Here is an example on zipping:

```
//Zip file
using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
{
    using (ZipArchive archive = new ZipArchive(ms, ZipArchiveMode.Create, true))
    {
        ZipArchiveEntry archiveEntry = archive.CreateEntry("tblAccount.csv");
        using (StreamWriter streamWriter = new StreamWriter(archiveEntry.Open()))
        {
            streamWriter.Write(accountSB.ToString());
        }

        //Continue adding ZipArchiveEntry objects (files) as necessary...
    }

    ms.Flush();
    ms.Position = 0;
    ms.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);

    //Return file...
}
```

If you decide to go with zipping multiple files then you can send the zip file on the response as follows:

```
HttpResponseMessage result = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.OK);
result.Content = new StreamContent(ms);
result.Content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/octet-stream");
result.Content.Headers.ContentDisposition = new ContentDispositionHeaderValue("attachment") { FileName = "Tables.zip" };
return result;
```

Alternatively you could write the CSV content right on the response (though you may want to consider only returning one CSV formatted response at a time):

```
//Response
HttpResponseMessage result = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.OK);
result.Content = new StringContent(accountSB.ToString(), System.Text.Encoding.UTF8, "text/csv");
return result;
```

Comment: Thanks Matt. Opening as Zipfile is not an option to the user. We can consider pushing the data into Workbook with multiple Worksheets if multiple CSV files is challenging. I posted the same question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49412973/generating-excel-file-with-multiple-worksheets-using-datatables-data-on-asp-net

Comment: If you ultimately decide against the Excel option then you may want to consider simply returning individual CSV-formatted strings from Web API endpoints (one string per endpoint or many through the use of custom defined return models). Then you can just get the basic data without the need for extra processing steps. It sounds like you had considered writing a web frontend so maybe that part of the app could be used to implement the highlighting requirement (if you'll have the full data set on the frontend).